# Add 'active' class to parent of parent in wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress, nav

I want to add "active" class to ancestor of **active menu item**

[image]

I found this code but it add class to parent even when not active grandchild

```
    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'add_menu_parent_class' );
function add_menu_parent_class( $items ) {

    $parents = array();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        if ( $item->menu_item_parent && $item->menu_item_parent > 0 ) {
            $parents[] = $item->menu_item_parent;
        }
    }

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        if ( in_array( $item->ID, $parents ) ) {
            $item->classes[] = 'menu-parent-item'; 
        }
    }

    return $items;    
}
```

How to make it by function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery:

To add the active class to the parent menu item of li.current-post-ancestor:

```
$('.li.current-post-ancestor').parent().parent().addClass('active');
```

Note that the first parent() takes you to the parent ul element, and the second parent() takes you to the li parent of the ul.

I always prefer to do something in PHP, but sometimes it much much easier to hack it in jQuery!  You could get really fancy and write a [custom menu walker](http://shinraholdings.com/62/custom-nav-menu-walker-function/), but that's a lot of work.